# Java transfer files via UDP. Compressed files are damaged?

Tags: java, file, networking, udp, file-transfer

i'm trying to transfer Files with a DatagrammSocket in Java. I'm reading the files into 4096 Byte pieces. We are using ACK, so all pieces are in the right order, we tried pdf, exe, jpg and lot more stuff successfully, but iso, zip and 7z are not working. They have exactly the same size afterwards. Do you have any idea?

Reading the Parts:

```
byte[] b = new byte[FileTransferClient.PACKAGE_SIZE - 32];
FileInputStream read = new FileInputStream(file);
read.skip((part - 1) * (FileTransferClient.PACKAGE_SIZE - 32));
read.read(b);
content = b;
```

Writing the Parts:

```
stream = new FileOutputStream(new File(this.filePath));
stream.write(output);
...
stream.write(output);
stream.close();
```

(Sorry for great grammar, i'm German)

Comment: UDP delivery is not guaranteed. You should use TCP for this.

Comment: I have to use UDP, I have my own protocol to get sure everything gets transferred and is not damaged. So byte by byte is the same...

Comment: You haven't posted all the relevant code. How does `content` get onto the wire? and how is `output` formed?

Comment: Do *NOT* assume that a UDP "read" will read all the data you sent all at once.  *ALWAYS* be prepared to "read" in a loop, until you get all the data you're expecting.

Comment: @paulsm4 A UDP read will do exactly that. You're thinking of TCP, a streaming protocol. UDP is a datagram protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `write()` method calls are assuming that the entire buffer was filled by `receive().` You must use the length provided with the `DatagramPacket:`

```
datagramSocket.receive(packet);
stream.write(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), packet.getLength());
```

If there is overhead in the packet, e.g. a sequence number, which there should be, you will need to adjust the offset and length accordingly.

NB TCP will ensure 'everything gets transferred and is not damaged'.